# Make Bootstrap images (svg) closer together

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

```
<footer id="contact">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <h3 class="connect">Let's Talk</h3>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
      <li role="presentation"><a href="https://twitter.com/">
<img src="images/social/twitter.svg" alt="twitter logo"></a></li>
      <li role="presentation"><a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/"> <img src="images/social/linkedin.svg" alt="linkedin logo"></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy;</p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I want the twitter and linked in images to be closer. Cant seem to figure it out...help! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4A1Gv.png)

Comment: you can either make the width of `<ul>` to some extinct like to 30% or so.

Comment: do you have any css markup that might be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Youre using twitter bootstrap, so you can take advantage of its bundled grid classes. It's is worth noting that items inside a `.row` item will be subject to it's default negative margin (used to counteract the column guttering), so should be wrapped in a a `.col-xs-12` at the least so that they are aligned with other column items.

I have included some suggested classes to limit the width of the `.nav-tabs` section using both [`.col-**-x`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options) and [`.col-**-offset-x`](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting).

```
<footer id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <h3 class="connect">Let's Talk</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-4">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified">
                    <li role="presentation">
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/">
                            <img src="images/social/twitter.svg" alt="twitter logo">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li role="presentation">
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/in/">
                            <img src="images/social/linkedin.svg" alt="linkedin logo">
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p class="copyright">Copyright &copy;</p>
    </div>
</footer>
```